# Jquery Reading Position progress between article content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

In this example 
http://jsfiddle.net/SnJXQ/61/
that reading progress indicator but it's width increased from top of site !!
 
 
**but we need progress bar width begin increasing** 
**when article content div reached until end of article content** 
and this is a sample code that we need to edit
HTML

```
<div class="bar-long"></div>
<header>Header & Menu
    <br>header and menu content
    <p>Header & Menu
        <br>header and menu content
        <p>Header & Menu
            <br>header and menu content
            <p>
</header>
    <h1>Begin Article <br>(Need show Bar from here) </h1>

<p>
    <article>
        <div class="bar-long2">article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />article content
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="bar-long3">
             <h1>EndEndEnd<br> (Need width Bar 100%</h1>

        </div>
    </article>
    <footer>
         <h1>Footer</h1>

        <div class="footer">
             <h4>Footer</h4> 
                <h4>Footer</h4> 
             <h4>Footer</h4> 
             <h4>Footer</h4> 
                <h4>Footer</h4> 
        </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS

```
 .bar-long {
     height: 5px;
     background-color: #009ACF;
     width: 0px;
     z-index: 1000;
     position: fixed;
     top: 50px;
     left: 0;
 }
 body {
     height:2000px;
 }
```

Jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

     // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page
     var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $('article').height());

     $('.bar-long').css('width', scrollPercent + "%");

 });
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/SnJXQ/68/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its a little complicated but finally

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page
    var scrollwin = $(window).scrollTop();
    var articleheight = $('article').outerHeight(true);
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(scrollwin >= $('article').offset().top){
        if(scrollwin <= ($('article').offset().top + articleheight)){
            $('.bar-long').css('width', ((scrollwin - $('article').offset().top) / articleheight) * 100 + "%"  );
        }else{
            $('.bar-long').css('width',"100%");
        }
    }else{
        $('.bar-long').css('width',"0px");
    }


});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/SnJXQ/67/)

let me explain what is going on here

the width percentage will come from  the part of the article which pass the scrollTop and divided by article height  to get the percentage of that part

in if statement I create 2nd if statement to stop the blue bar at 100% not increase each time we scroll down the article

So whatever your article height this code will work

Comment: Thanks very much. and this code that work very well with any height or width .

`    var articleheight = $('article').height() - $(window).height();
`

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating in a wrong way, this is the correct one:

```
var scrollPercent = 100 * ($(window).scrollTop() - $('article').offset().top) / $('article').height();
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/SnJXQ/62/

Note: I set a `background-color` to `article` to see the calc better.

Comment: lmgonzalves Thanks for fast answer but if height of body increased like here 
https://jsfiddle.net/SnJXQ/63/
 not work as well !!
we need it works with every height value

Comment: Does not matter, because the calc is only relative to the `selected element`. You need to change the `background-color: lightgray;` to the `.bar-long2` (the `selected element`), and you can see it's working very well :) https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/SnJXQ/66/